# Chosen multiselect adds extra "" to array of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-chosen

I have a form element that is using Chosen to render a multi-select input, like so

`<%= f.collection_select :application_regions, ApplicationRegion.all, :identifier, :name, {}, { class: 'chosen_select', multiple: true } %>`

The value of ApplicationRegions.all is an array with a single value

`[#<ApplicationRegion:0x007fc61aeb3100 @identifier="FOO", @name="BAR">]`

I am initializing chosen like so:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('.chosen-container').remove()
  $('.chosen_select').chosen
    allow_single_deselect: true
    width: '100%'
```

The input correctly displays a list with a single option `BAR` but the output array is `["", "BAR"]` - where is that extra `""` coming from, and how do I get rid of it?

I had thought that taking out the `allow_single_deselect: true` would take care of this, but the behavior remains (I did a `spring stop` just to be sure)

Comment: Do you know about `:include_blank => false`? Did you read the documentation for `f.collection_select` ?

Comment: There is no blank value in the generated select input, `:include_blank` does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Зелёный](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057388/%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) was on the right track. Adding `include_hidden: false` to the `collection_select` solves the issue of the extra `''` in the output.